# How to change UISwitch name in iphone?

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize UISwitch button in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087546/how-to-customize-uiswitch-button-in-iphone)

How to change name of `UISwitch` (like on,off) i am creating `UISwitch` in Xib so i want to change the name like **yes** or **no**.

Comment: You could just use a custom UISegmentedControl as described [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087546/how-to-customize-uiswitch-button-in-iphone)

Comment: But i am creating UISwitch in Interface builder so possivle to change text in UISwitch Text

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a custom switch...

http://www.catamount.com/blog/1063/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/

this should help

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API method for changing the text on an `UISwitch`

You should use a `UISegmentedControl` or a [Custom `UISwitch`](http://www.catamount.com/blog/1063/uicustomswitch-customizing-uiswitch-color-it-change-labels/)

Answer (score 0):

This one I found is very useful for creating the custom switch

```
http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/
```

You can create the custom switch and there will not be any problem in apple approval.