# How to change the UISwitch default color(blue)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios4

How to change the default color(blue) of a UISwitch?

Comment: nowadays (2019) it's just the badly-named `.onTintColor` .  Note that this has no relation to the usual "tintColor".

Answer (score 71):

I think what you are looking for is something like this

```
UISwitch *testSwitch; //just something I made up
[testSwitch setOnTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Answer (score 50):

In Xcode 5 and iOS 7 it's now in the attributes inspector:

[image]

Changing the On Tint will change the button's color when it's turned on.

[image]

I hope that's what you were looking for! Even though you posted that question like three years ago.

Answer (score 25):

**Swift 3**
**Swift 4**

workable solution

```
var switcher = UISwitch()
switcher.onTintColor = .green
switcher.tintColor = .green
```

Answer (score 8):

Prior to iOS 5, without writing your own custom `UISwitch` control, perhaps using a `UISegmentedControl`, Apple did not allow you to change the color of a standard `UISwitch`.

There is a private property **`setAlternateColor: YES`** which will change the color to orange, and you would need to create a category for the `UISwitch` class, but this will not be approved in the Apple review process.

Here are a few custom `UISwitch` projects for use in iOS 3.0 - 4.1:

1. http://osiris.laya.com/projects/rcswitch/
2. http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2010/07/30/custom-uiswitch/
3. StackOverflow Anser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5088099/171206 (using `UISegmentedControl`)

Introduced in iOS 5, the `UISwitch` now has an `onTintColor` property.

```
[mySwitch setOnTintColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3:

```
yourSwitch.onTintColor = .red
```

Answer (score 3):

Set tint color for a specific UISwitch:

```
var switcher = UISwitch()
switcher.onTintColor = .red
switcher.tintColor = .red
```

Set tint color for your app:

```
let switchApperence = UISwitch.appearance()
switchApperence.tintColor = .red
switchApperence.onTintColor = .red
```

Comment: Why do we need to set the tintColor attribute? It is working for me as expected with just onTintColor being set.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, with iOS5 you can change the color of the switch with the property onTintColor.

```
UISwitch *s = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
s.on = YES;
s.onTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:s];
[s release];
```

produce this

[image]

I hope this help !