# Creating my custom UISwitch

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiswitch

i am looking for a solution to customize a `UISwitch` 
the desigred looks lie this :

[image]

how would you managed it?

Comment: use ABSwitch https://github.com/ablfx/ABSwitch/

Comment: take look http://www.raywenderlich.com/23424/photoshop-for-developers-creating-a-custom-uiswitch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23424/photoshop-for-developers-creating-a-custom-uiswitch) is a tutorial which can help you to create custom `UISwitch`. It mention to ways to create custom `UISwitch`. Concept is to subclass `UISwitch` class and add custom things in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UIbutton` and toggle its image for On/Off. 
Or else if you want to make animation to toggle On/Off you should use your custom view. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281735/custom-uiswitch-with-image)