# I want to add my own image to switch Control in ios using Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I tried to add my own image to switch Control in xamarin forms using rendering concept but i am unable to override the existing image.Below is my code.
In shared project i added code like this

```
  Switch switcher = new ExtendedSwitchnew();
```

and in ios

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedSwitchnew),typeof(SwitchRenderernew))]
namespace test.iOS
{
public class SwitchRenderernew :SwitchRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {


            UIImage imgon = UIImage.FromFile("Images/switchon.png");
            UIImage imgoff = UIImage.FromFile("Images/switchoff.png");

            Control.OnImage = imgon;
            Control.OffImage = imgoff;

        }

    }
}
}
```

Help me.Thanks in advace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom UISwitch with image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281735/custom-uiswitch-with-image)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The above link is related to ios but my requirement is to change the switch default image using xamarin forms (ios).

Comment: If you would read the answers to the linked custom UISWitch SO, you would see that it is not possible since iOS7, In the iOS docs: `offImage/onImage : In iOS 7, this property has no effect.` :  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwitch_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISwitch/onImage Thus you would need to create your own custom Switch-style control